# Search Active Directory for an OU using a partial path to the OU

Tags: c#, active-directory, directory, ldap, directoryservices

Is there a way in AD Query syntax, to find an OU's full path by searching on its partial path?

For example, the full path to my OU is:

```
OU=Clerks,OU=OfficeA,OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=local
```

Now, I'd like to try and search and find that object by using the partial path:

```
OU=Clerks,OU=OfficeA
```

I'd like to be able to search something like:

```
(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(path=Clerks/OfficeA*))
```

I can't find any syntax examples of how to accomplish something like this.  A program I'm developing requires that I get the paths to a lot of OU's which all have a common structure in the last two levels of OU's, however they can be nested at any given depth in the domain otherwise.  If I can search somehow like this, it would be easy to get the full path just searching by the last two OU nested levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you want to do exists on pure LDAP implementation it's a feature called **ExtensibleMatch** wich seems to be correctly explained in [this wiki article](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) . You will also found something helpfull examples [here](http://help.globalscape.com/help/eft5/admin/advanced_ldap_filtering.htm).

But it's not present in Active-Directory

So here is a method writen in C# that exploit the `Parent` propertie of a `DirectoryEntry`.

```
   static List<DirectoryEntry> OuInTheFormOf(DirectoryEntry deBase, string ou1, string ou2)
    {
      List<DirectoryEntry> deList = null;

      /* Directory Search
       */
      DirectorySearcher dsLookFor = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
      dsLookFor.Filter = ou1;
      dsLookFor.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
      dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ou");

      SearchResultCollection srcOUs = dsLookFor.FindAll();

      if (srcOUs.Count != 0)
      {
        deList = new List<DirectoryEntry>();

        foreach (SearchResult srOU in srcOUs)
        {
          DirectoryEntry deOU = srOU.GetDirectoryEntry();
          if (deOU.Parent.Name.ToUpper() == ou2.ToUpper())
            deList.Add(deOU);
        }
      }
      return deList;
    }
```

Here is the usage :

```
  /* Connection to Active Directory
   */
  DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr");

  List<DirectoryEntry> l = OuInTheFormOf(deBase, "ou=Clerks", "ou=OfficeA");

  foreach (DirectoryEntry deTmp in l)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(deTmp.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value);
  }
```