# Search when NOT in OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I want to search in the AD with LDAP, with a condition that people are not in a specific OU (see example)

```
Domain.local
- [OU] Location A
-- [OU] Users
-- [OU] Computers
- [OU] Location B
-- [OU] Users
-- [OU] Computers
- [OU] Location C
-- [OU] Users
-- [OU] Computers
```

In my filter I want all users BUT the users from Location B/Users

**is** this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ExtensibleMatch** explained [here](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) allow to build filters on the DN path, but it's not supported in Active Directory. As far as I know you've got the following solution to do what you want:

- Multiple search, one for each OU except the one you don't want
- Two search, one global, one for the OU you don't want objects, and you suppress the entries from the second search in the first one.
- Use an attribute in AD to make the distinction for users in Location B. For example  the attribute called `OU` which is inherited from `organizationalPerson` class. you set it with "locationB" (it's multivaluated)

The third solution is the one I use. My advice in your case is :

1. Test if OU attribute is used in your Directory for users or inetorgpersons if so select an other attribute

   (&(|(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(objectclass=user))(ou=*))
2. by scripting, by programming,by using LDIF populate the attribute you choose and keep it in use

If you are programmin with C# you've got the information of "parent" for an object as I explain in a [simalary question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872838/search-active-directory-for-an-ou-using-a-partial-path-to-the-ou/5874554#5874554) so you can sort object on this criterium.

Comment: That's some useful stuff right there, I'm gna try them out :) Thanks!