# Exclude OU from search

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search when NOT in OU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208243/search-when-not-in-ou)

I am trying to exclude an `OU` (Organizational Unit) from a search

I am doing on active directory so that I would not show people that have been terminated or are no longer employed with us.

These people exist in an `OU` called "Suspended" which I do not want to show. I tried doing something along the lines of `(!OU=Suspended)` .however that does not work. I am using .net and System.DirectoryServices. Here is my current search filter:

```
search.Filter = String.Format ( "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sn={0}*)(!employeeType=Student)(!(memberOf=CN=NoDirectoryEntry,OU=Groups,OU=Staff,OU=SPFLDCOL,DC=scad,DC=spfldcol,DC=edu)))", lname );
```

Comment: Show us a bit more code, need some context + what specific error (if any)

Comment: This is actually a good question, but it has already been answered, se comment above

Comment: @RhysW: "OU" is pretty standard terminology when talking about AD. This is not about databases. Maybe one could also ask for more details with a little more courtesy :)

Comment: @Paolo My mistake i misread the word, by the by it was meant to be light humour and courteous, things dont always come across that way though...

Comment: @RhysW: I don't think you were nasty either :) It's just that I think that (especially with new users) one should be as encouraging as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exclude an OU using a filter in a LDAP search in Active-Direcory.

Because the standard LDAP discribe a LDAP-SEARCH as kind of function with 4 parameters :

1. The nod where begin the search which is a Distinguish Name (DN)
2. The attibutes you want to be brougth back
3. The depth of the search (base, one-level, subtree)
4. The filter.

The solutions remaining are :

- To look for each others OU.
- To use a dedicated attribute for each object un the suspended OU and to filter with this attribute.

Comment: could I specify a specific OU to search in then?

Comment: Yes you can specify the DN of an OU as the nod where you begin to search.