# DirectorySearcher Filter

Tags: c#, active-directory

When I run this query

```
// Next row is used to login to AD
DirectoryEntry entry = GetEntry(domain, adminUser, adminPassword);
// Here starts the query
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
{
    SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
    Filter = "(&" +
        "(objectClass=user)" +
        // "(distinguishedname=*OU=Ingegneria*)" +
        "(givenname=s*)" +
        "(samaccountname=*100)" +
    ")"
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();
```

I get six entries and that's correct.
All records, if I use `record.GetDirectoryEntry()` have

```
distinguishedname: CN=xxx,OU=Utenti,OU=Ingegneria,DC=xxx,DC=xxx
```

Anyway if I remove comment on `distinguishedname` part of the filter, I get zero entries!!
I also tried to use `search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");` without luck.
How can I search `distinguishedname` in filter?

**UPDATE:**
If I try to use `"(distinguishedname=*)" +` in filter , I still get six records, so I think I can search on distinguishedname...
**UPDATE2:**
I also tried to use code in [Search Active Directory for an OU using a partial path to the OU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872838/search-active-directory-for-an-ou-using-a-partial-path-to-the-ou):

```
Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(ou=Ingegneria))";
```

but I have zero entries (I got two if I remove `(objectClass=user)` part)

Comment: try removing `OU=Ingegneria*` and see what happens

Comment: @Shai: I need that part of the filter... anyway take a look at my update.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872838/search-active-directory-for-an-ou-using-a-partial-path-to-the-ou - that might help you search by OU.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: I'm sorry... it didn't help: should I change the whole query to first get OUs and then query each of them? If so, I really don't like this idea... Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to query just that, then you should **bind** to that container in your initial connect:

```
// Next row is used to login to AD
string ldapPath = "LDAP://OU=Ingegneria,DC=xxx,DC=xxx";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = GetEntry(ldapPath, adminUser, adminPassword);

// Here starts the query
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot)
{
    SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
    Filter = "(&" +
        "(objectClass=user)" +
        "(givenname=s*)" +
        "(samaccountname=*100)" +
    ")"
};

search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();
```

That way, you also massively reduce the space in AD that needs to be searched, thus speeding up your search.

And if you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", "OU=Ingegneria,DC=xxx,DC=xxx");

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "s*";
qbeUser.SamAccountName = "*100";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal"
    UserPrincipal userFound = found as UserPrincipal;

    if(userFound != null)
    {
       // do something with your user principal here....
    }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's really complete. I'll take a look as soon as possible. My only doubt is that OU to search on is dynamic (is part of runtime user defined filter)... but I can probably find a way to manage it. Thanks

Comment: Just to be complete: is there a way to search OUs (or part of `distinguishedname`, as in my question) binding AD root?

Comment: Thanks anyway, your answer is really useful and shows new objects (to me) I can use. Your example worked, naturally! Just a note: `DistinguishedName` in `Principal` class is marked as read-only, so I cannot use a filter on it... I don't know the reason, but it's Microsoft design, so probably that's just the way it should be!! :)