# When Searching Active Directory Groups Using PrincipalContext Certain UserPrincipal Properties are not Returned

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am writing a C# application to display users within a user supplied security group.  It seems like all my test cases work except when I search against "Domain Users".  When I do neither Surname or GivenName will return values.  All other groups return those values.  I'm stumped.

Test 1: Domain Admins

Results: All Surname and GivenName displayed in GridView

Test 2: Domain Users

Results: No Surname or GivenName's are displayed

Note: If I change the properties to any other AD User Property, e.g., Name, SAM, etc., those all display without issue.

```
namespace adsearch
{
    public partial class frmViewGroupMembers : Form
    {
        private string group;
        private DataTable GroupMembers = new DataTable();

        public frmViewGroupMembers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ShowGroupMembers(string groupName) {
            GroupMembers.Columns.Add("Last Name");
            GroupMembers.Columns.Add("First Name");


            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.local")) {
                using (GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName))
                {
                    foreach (UserPrincipal user in group.GetMembers(true).OfType<UserPrincipal>())
                    {
                        GroupMembers.Rows.Add(user.Surname, user.GivenName);
                    }                  
                }
            }

            dgvGroupMembers.DataSource = GroupMembers;
            dgvGroupMembers.Sort(dgvGroupMembers.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            this.Show();
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in Active Directory to confirm that the User has the required fields filled in? Often the assumption is made that filling in the "Display Name" is enough, but both the "First Name" (GivenName) and "Last Name" (SurName) need to be filled in for GivenName and SurName to be populated.

[image]

'

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes, those fields are populated.  What is strange is that every other security group shows up correct with all the users displayed, but Domain User show a line item for each user but does not show the Given and Surname.  It's odd.

Comment: Is this a group that you can delete and re-create?  Over the last 10 years or so, we've seen 4-5 instances where a group/user gets corrupted and we have to delete them and then re-create them.  It's worked every time so far.  This may be a group that has to be in place 100% of the time for you, which would make such a drastic step impossible, but if you can delete/re-create it, it may resolve the issue.

Comment: It's the built-in Domain Users group.  I ended up putting this on the back burner and used PowerShell commands to satisfy the immediate need, but it'll be a bug in my brain until I figure it out.  Next chance I have to work on it I'm going to open up the User Object properties to see if all properties are returning blank or just, by chance, the ones I want.

Comment: The UserPrincipal object does not expose the "givenName" and "sn" (sur name) properties.  It looks like it does, but it really doesn't.  Take a look at using a DirectorySearcher:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451618/directorysearcher-filter

Comment: Brilliant. I had seen that class but there was a reason I didn’t use it but after a long day like today I can’t remember why, lol. I’ll take a look and let you know. If this works you’re a life saver!!!

Comment: I was thinking about your suggestion, which I'll try, but I am able to see givenName and sn in other groups just not Domain Users.  When I run my program I can look at any other group and it displays correctly, that's what's so odd.